# Stretch for Squats muscles

Tags: squats, stretching

I'm not a professional athlete or anything, but I swim about 1,5 miles and run 5-8 miles everyday. I can't afford a trainer and don't have time for gym (except on weekends...).

For a couple of days I've been doing squats (4 series of 30, 3 hours apart of each other). The exercise itself is not that difficult, the problem is that my legs are starting to hurt in a place i can't stretch them! The "pain" is located in the outside-upper corner of the thigh...

What is a good stretch for that part?

**Edit1:**
According to [this image](http://www.fpnotebook.com/_media/ThighAnatomyMuscleAnterior.gif) I would say "Tensor Fasciae Latae" muscle and the upper part of the "Sartorius" muscle, on both thighs...
And clarification: the pain is not bad, just annoying... I feel like "oh maybe if I give that a good stretch..."

Comment: Can you clarify where on your leg it is hurting? Not sure where the "upper corner of the tie" is on the leg.

Comment: @JohnP edited for clarification

Answer (score 6):

Check out [Limber 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSSDLDhbacc) by a guy called Joe DeFranco. It's a few exercises/stretches which really helped me with my squat form. I used to have pain in the front of my hip when squatting but I started doing this 3 times a week and I noticed improvements after only a few days. Your lower back will also thank you for doing this. Some of the exercises require a bit of equipment but it is all pretty cheap and easy to find.

Comment: that first seems just like what I need... i just need to get a pipe...

Answer (score 4):

When the upper outer front part of my leg feels tight or painful during squats, I find the best results from stretching my glutes. Stretches like yoga's pigeon pose:

[image: Pigeon pose]

...or pushing my knees out from a deep 3rd world squat:

[image: 3rd world squat]

...seem to help the most. Foam rolling the area that actually hurts can help too.

Answer (score 3):

There is debate over how beneficial stretching actually is, but for these hard to stretch areas a foam roller (or similar tools for reaching smaller areas, such as the spikey balls) can be very useful for releasing tension short term, similar to a massage. They are pretty straight forward to use, but guides can be found online through a quick search.

Combining the foam roller with light exercises to focus on engaging and strengthening the muscle that is producing the "pain", should allow it to relax.

Always be sure the "pain" is not due to injury before doing anything.